# Scipy's curve_fit with a matrix or array as initial guesss

Tags: python

here's a minimal working example:

```
x_data = np.linspace(-5, 5, num=50)
y_data = 2.9 * np.sin(1.5 * x_data) + np.random.normal(size=50)

def test_func(x, *c):
    a = c[0][0]
    b = c[0][1]
    return a * np.sin(b * x)

p0 = np.array([[2,2],[2,2]])

params, params_covariance = curve_fit(test_func, x_data, y_data, p0)

print(params)
```

This returns

```
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

I believe the problem is that `p0` is a matrix, and `curve_fit` is having trouble having that as a first guess. Is there a way to get this to work?

PS: I am aware that, in the above example, there is no need for `p0` to be a matrix, and I could just define the function as `test_func(x, a, b)` and use as a first guess `p0=[2,2]`. However, the above example is just a simplification of my code, and in my code I really need the first guess `p0` to be a matrix.

Comment: why not drop the `*` and then access for indexing as `args[0]` etc.

Comment: @Chris_Rands Actually that was what I was initially doing. However, I then need to use SciPy's optimise, and I get errors e.g. "TypeError: function takes x positional arguments but a lot more were given". Perhaps that should have been my question in the first place.

Comment: Then you might call the scipy function the wrong way?

Comment: @L3n95 I guess that becomes my question then. How do I input into curve_fit a matrix as the initial guess p0?

Comment: @FBadone so `f`is the function. What "shape" have `xdata` and `z`. And `p0` is `params`?

Comment: @L3n95 the function is in 2D, so f(x,y). `x` and `y` are initially (200,). I then use `xdata = np.vstack((X.ravel(), Y.ravel()))`. This gives xdata a shape (2, 40000). `z` has shape (40000,). The initial guess is `p0 = params` which is a matrix of arbitrary size.

Answer (score 0):

Just pass it as a normal param and use the indices to select the values.

```
def f(m):
   print(m[0,0]) # --> 0
   print(m[0,1]) # --> 1
   print(m[1,0]) # --> 2
   print(m[1,1]) # --> 3

params = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])
f(params)
```

Or if you don't know the size of your array:

```
def f(m):
    for i in range(m.shape[0]):
        for j in range(m.shape[1]):
            print(m[i,j])
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my question was wrong in the first place so I've rephrased it.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a small example of a function that accesses and changes some element in your numpy array:

```
import numpy as np

params = np.array([[0,1],[2,3]])


def fn(a):
    print(a[0][0])
    a[0][0] = 5

fn(params)

print(params[0][0])
```

Note: We use no `*` here to indicate a reference to `params` like we would in other languages like C.  This is because the reference is passed by default for `np.array`s, so we can access and edit the elements in the passed array within the `fn()` function.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I think my question was wrong in the first place so I've rephrased it.

Comment: No promises but you could try: `curve_fit(f, xdata.resize(-1), z, p0.resize(-1))` to turn your matrices into arrays with resize (which curve_fit likes better).  Then you would just want to add a line to your `f()` function that will resize the array into an a matrix, or access the individual list elements.  Something like `tempmatrix = np.resize(a,[2,2])` then you can access elements from `tempmatrix`

Comment: Thanks. However using `p0.resize(-1)` returns `ValueError: negative dimensions not allowed`.

Comment: Oh yeah, you will need to have p0 as array to resize like this: `curve_fit(f, np.asarray(xdata).resize(-1), z, np.asarray(p0).resize(-1))`

Comment: Same error. I've now rewritten the question, hopefully it makes more sense. Thanks again.